# how to retrieve key from siblings in riak

Tags: riak, riak-2i

I have sibling like this "RAtqxEhJvwUGkv54TmRlUaOXwEk" in riak.
Now I want to retrive key of this sibling using curl GET request.
Is their any way to find out key

Answer (score 0):

The key is the same for all siblings of an object, that's why they are called siblings. If you want to retrieve a particular sibling, use `vtag` request parameter. For example, `curl http://127.0.0.1:8098/buckets/MY_BUCKET/keys/MY_KEY?vtag=RAtqxEhJvwUGkv54TmRlUaOXwEk`. See https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/latest/developing/api/http/fetch-object/#siblings-examples

Comment: yes. But I have only sibling with me, can I get corresponding key from sibling

Comment: @anilbc Can you describe your use-case? I can't think of a situation when you have just a sibling ID without any context such as key and a bucket type and name.

Comment: I have bucket type, bucket name , sibling only. On that basis, I need to retrieve key or record for particular siblings.

Comment: @anilbc Yes, but how come you don't have a key? Which Riak command can return a bucket and a sibling, but not a key?